# How to remove extra space between ellipsis and text in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a plain input where I want to have an ellipsis. But for some reason, there is extra space between text and ellipsis in Firefox. I suggest that the browser can't display the whole character that follows next and left space for it. You can notice this by increasing the width of the input by 1px at a time. In other browsers, there is no such problem. Is there any solution how to get rid of that space?

```css
input {
  width: 110px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet">
```

[image]

Comment: What browser version are you using?

Comment: @RichardDobroň Firefox v101.0.1

Comment: I don't see the same problem on my local machine, Firefox v101.0.1, Chrome 102.0.5005.115,  Windows 11. [screenshot](https://ibb.co/7Q4fmsN)

Comment: It could be a font issue, what font you are using?

Comment: @Anton The issue reproduces from the snippet above and I'm using the default browser font. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipIgG.jpg)

Comment: That strange, try opening new window in private mode. It could be a setting or an extension for Firefox.